# MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017 in mac

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Can someone explain why the error was thrown and how to fix it in detail?

```
reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) { 'localhost:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: undefined
  }
```

Comment: Is the **mongod** process running?

Comment: Yes, running this issue has been fixed by adding { family : 4 } in mongoose connect. Thanks!

Comment: **Working Code**
`mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test',{family: 4, useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true}).then(() => app.listen(5000, () => {console.log('Port 5000 is running...')})).catch(error => console.log(error));`